# Can't open Sqlite on Git Bash

Tags: sqlite, git-bash

I'm trying to access my sqlite database on my current directory at `/c/wamp/www/laravel5` on my local project folder, with windows as my OS. I added the sqlite3 executable on the directory.

The database doesn't seem to open using git bash. When using the default command  in windows command prompt it works seamlesly. `sqlite3.exe storage/database.sqlite`

Tried on Git Bash:

```
$ ./sqlite3.exe
```

and

```
$ ./sqlite3.exe storage/database.sqlite
```

These didn't work.
The error message is:

```
bash: sqlite3.exe: command not found
```

Here's a snapshot:
[image]

I'd like to see the database tables and schema using git bash since it has cooler font colors compare with the windows cmd.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean with "didn't work"? Nothing? An error message? Your computer exploded?

Comment: Hi @CL. already updated the post, added the error message.

Comment: What is the current directory? (`pwd`)

Comment: Stated on the post `/c/wamp/www/laravel5`

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l`.

Comment: Already added a snapshot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you have the same problem I had, then see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285349/after-upgrade-to-git-bash-2-8-2-cannot-run-sqlite3).

In short, using "winpty" to start sqlite3 worked:

```
$ winpty sqlite3
```

Comment: still very useful! also works with mysql (i.e., `winpty mysql`)

Comment: This works, but then I can't Ctrl+C to exit sqlite anymore.

Comment: This is true. It gets into a state where I need /bin/kill to exit it if I issue any SQL commands other than sqlite3's own "begins with a dot" ones. I suspect any line I type that doesn't begin with a . will put it into this state.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the previous answer by @user172431, add the following alias to your .bashrc

```
alias sqlite3="winpty sqlite3.exe"
```

This will make the workflow a tad quicker and feel like a ninja rock-star in the process. I use this shortcut via Git Bash