# After upgrade to GIT bash 2.8.2, cannot run sqlite3

Tags: git, sqlite

In the version I had (1.9.x?), it worked ok, but now it just hangs.

In the screen snippet, I show Git bash (with no response), Windows CMD, and Cygwyin.

The latter two work fine; In each case I'm the same folder where the sqlite3.exe is located.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to run it with *winpty* like this: `winpty sqlite3.exe`

Comment: Not sure what winpty is intended for, but this works.

Comment: If using in a script with STDIN, then you can't use winpty... methinks there's some hints here about what it happening.

Comment: `Git Bash will use MinTTY as terminal emulator, which sports a resizable window non-rectangular selections and a Unicode font. Windows console programs (such as interactive Python) must be launched via 'winpty' to work in MinTTY.`    https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/master/installer/install.iss

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0 the windows client was re-written with a lot of modifications.
This is the windows forked version:
https://git-for-windows.github.io/

In your case you need to verify that you have the `sqlite3.sh` (since you did not used the `sqlite3.exe` in the attached screenshot)

Also verify that you have execute permissions on the file as well

Comment: is it significantly different from the "upstream" version, distributed from https://git-scm.com/download/win ?

Comment: Nope, since version 2 GitHub took ownership on the windows distribution and they are maintaining the official version

Comment: In other cases, the ".exe" extension isn't needed. It does have execute permissions. And if I add the ".exe" extension, it still just hangs. I noted above that if I run with winpty it *does* work. So for now, I'll just have to remember to run like this: $ winpty sqlite3