# No Such File or Directory using SQLite with Git Bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, git-bash

I am very new to SQLite3 (very new). I am following a tutorial on how to create a database using SQLite3, and I am trying to run it with Git Bash. When I enter the command `cd /c/sqlite` in Git Bash, however, I get the error "no such file or directory". I am using PyCharm, so my python file is in users>myname>pycharmprojects (if this has anything to do with it). I am very sorry if this is a simple solution, but I am just beginning.

Comment: I think it's added to the PATH on installation. Can you try typing just `sqlite3` at the Git Bash prompt?

Comment: @mechanical_meat when I do that, it tells me `command not found` :(

Comment: Ah, I saw a related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37352276/42346 maybe that will work for you.

Comment: No luck, I get `cannot start 'sqlite3': Not found in PATH` .

Comment: Oh, I should've thought of this before: you may not have the command-line tool installed. The `sqlite3` module comes with Python, but to access SQLite outside of Python the command-line interface would need to be installed.

Comment: How do I install the command-line interface?

Comment: That would be OS-dependent. Are you on Windows by chance?

Comment: Yes I am on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! So Git Bash was not recognizing sqlite3 because I didn't have sqlite in the proper file directory. So what I did was create a new folder in my C: directory (where Git Bash was looking), place my python file in that folder, and execute the following commands in Git Bash:

```
Amari@DESKTOP-myDesktop MINGW64 ~
$ pwd
/c/Users/amari

Amari@DESKTOP-myDesktop MINGW64 ~
$ cd /c/sqlite
```

And there it is! It worked!